# Signal for row added in QtableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I currently have a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which serves as a source to my `QTableView`. I wanted to know if there was a signal that I could connect to `QTableView` that would tell me that a new row was added?

Comment: Rows are a propert of the model, not view, so you should look for the signals on the model. A model can have rows added to it with zero views attached to it: a model and views lead separate lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not specified, I'm assuming Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.3.

Neither of them have what you want. This would be particularly hard to implement in a widget that serves for the Model-View framework as it does not implement something like the observer pattern.

The docs FYI:

[Qt 4.8 QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html)
[Qt 5.3 QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTableView.html)

Comment: Qt is full of observer pattern, its is everywhere, this is what signals and slots do.

Answer (score 4):

`QTableView` doesn't have it directly, but `QTableView` has [`model`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#model) property of type [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html) which has this kind of signals.

- [rowsAboutToBeInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end)](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsAboutToBeInserted)
- [rowsInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end)](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted)